# NoHttpResponseException when running Selenium AndroidDriver on sendKeys method

Tags: android, selenium

I'm trying out Selenium AndroidDriver and trying to see if its suitable for us to use, but I'm running into problems getting it working as per the tutorial (http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver).

I'm using v 2.9.0 of the AndroidDriver (newest one from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list), and I'm trying to get it working using the RemoteServer approach (not my own Android WebView-based project). I'm running the tests on my MacBook, against a 2.2/Froyo emulator (I understand they're known not to work on Gingerbread), though I'm pretty sure I got the same problem running them from our Fedora boxes.

I have a JUnit project set up (again as per the tutorial); it compiles, runs, and loads google.com, but it chucks the following exception on element.sendKeys() :

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
Build info: version: '2.9.0', revision: '14289', time: '2011-10-20 21:54:54'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.6.7', java.version: '1.6.0_24'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Logcat has some exceptions along the lines of :
10-26 10:33:36.663: E/AndroidRuntime(451): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.MotionEvent.setSource

from the Selenium Android app (org.openqa.selenium.android.app), but the docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) suggest that this class/method has been around since API level 1.

Any advice gratefully received - happy to provide more info if required. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Having RTFDocs [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver#Introduction) more carefully, I found that I can make this work on a Froyo emulator using the [2.6.0 Selenium AndroidDriver APK](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=android-server-2.6.0.apk&can=1&q=android#makechanges).

It doesn't work on Gingerbread emulators, and I can't seem to get it to work on any Gingerbread devices as yet ( though devices are supposed to be supported).